# android cardview with rounded corners and shadow at 2 sides

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to use a cardview layout inside which there are other layouts. I want the cardview to have rounded corners (which I have done successfully). Now I want it to have shadow using card-elevation. But the problem is the shadow clearly avoids the corner radius and simply takes the cardview as a rectangular one like all the default cardviews.

Here's what I have done:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
               app:cardElevation="4dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#00000000"
                >


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/imagecard"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
                    >

                    <-- other layouts and views -->

                </RelativeLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Is there any way to implement what I am trying to do? And is there any way to avoid the shadow in 2 sides and keep it in the other 2 sides of the cardview?

I want something like this:

[image]

This is as far as I am going:

[image]

I am getting this when I put the cardview inside another parent cardview, with same cardCornerRadius and with giving the child cardview different margins in different sides. But it does not look very attractive.

Comment: You're setting `elevation` to 0, how do you expect to see the shadow? Plus, can you provide a screen in which you highlight what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry. That was an old code. I have updated it. Please check.

Comment: Add also what you get please

Comment: Use ShadowLayout for rounded corners and shadow at 2 sides.
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout

Comment: Just go with 1 card view, you don't need to use 2 of them. Plus, if the `CardView` is not what you want, I suggest you use [this tool](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/) to create a shadow and set as a background of your view

Comment: @LucaNicoletti yes. The tool is what I needed. Thanks!